# Passing props from function outside of component react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

thanks for taking time and reading this question. I have a function called loginstatus(), it evaluates the login status, I want it to alter state below . I don't know exactly where to place props, to be able to alter state. A brief description of where and why you did edits would be awesome, thanks in advance

```
const [count, setCount] = useState();
```

I have got everything else working I just want to find how change the state.

#### App.js

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import './App.css';
import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css'
import { Login } from './functions/login/login.js';
import { Logout } from './functions/login/logout.js';
import { loginstatus } from './functions/login/loginstatus.js';
import { currentloginid } from './functions/login/loginid.js';
import { ViewUser } from './functions/users/viewuser.js';
import { CreateUser } from './functions/users/createuser.js';
import { ViewAllUsersComponent } from './functions/users/viewallusers.js';
import { ViewQuestionComponent } from './functions/question/viewquestion.js';

function Process(props) {
  console.dir(props.count);
  if (props.count === "Logged In") {
    return (
      <>
        <ViewUser />
        <Logout setCount={props.setCount} />
        <CreateUser />
        <ViewAllUsersComponent />
        <ViewQuestionComponent />
      </>
    );
  } else {
    return <Login setCount={props.setCount} />;
  }
}
function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    loginstatus();
  }, []);

  return <Process count={count} setCount={setCount} />;
}


export default App;
```

#### loginstatus.js

```
export function loginstatus() {
    fetch('http://localhost/gotaquestion/api/api.php?action=loginstatus', 
        {
            method: 'GET',
            credentials: 'include'
        })
        .then(function(response) {
        if (response.status == 202) {
            props.setCount("Logged In");         
        } else {
            props.setCount("Not Logged In");
        }
        })
}
```

Comment: Please explain your problem more clearly.

Comment: src\functions\login\loginstatus.js
  Line 9:13:   'props' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 11:13:  'props' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.@SamridhTuladhar

Comment: you are missing props parameter in your `loginstatus.js`, create a props parameter as you have done in `function Process(props)`

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar I got this instead ```Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'setCount' of undefined```

Comment: Check the caller of `loginStatus` function now, the parameter that you have passed does not have the key value pair it requires, and accordingly, pass the required valus.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**props** is a special keyword in React, which stands for properties and is being used for passing data from one component to another. Your `loginStatus` function is NOT a react component and does not have access to your Components props.
More about it here: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

To achieve what you want, you can pass a function as an argument to your `loginStatus` function, that would look something like this:

More about functions and arguments here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

```
function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState();

  const loginSuccess = () => {
    setCount("Logged In"); 
  }

  const loginFailed = () => {
    setCount("Not Logged In"); 
  }

  useEffect(() => {
   loginstatus(loginSuccess, loginFailed);
  }, []);

  return <Process count={count} setCount={setCount} />;
}
```

**loginStatus.js**

```
export function loginstatus(successCb, errorCB) {
 fetch('http://localhost/gotaquestion/api/api.php?action=loginstatus', 
    {
        method: 'GET',
        credentials: 'include'
    })
    .then(function(response) {
    if (response.status == 202) {
        successCb();         
    } else {
        errorCb();
    }
    })
 }
```

Comment: awesome thanks, works great thanks for the brief explanation

Comment: Could you vote up the answer? And select it as the best answer?